# How do you define CFBundleIcons, CFBundleIconFiles, CFBundleIconFile?

Tags: ios, xcode

This is my first time submitting an app to App store, so please bear with me. I'm using iOS 6.0.

I have managed to get to the last step, where I needed to validate and submit my app to Apple for evaluation to be put onto AppStore. However, at the very end, it gave me this error message during validation:

[image]

So, I checked the Info.plist file to made sure that I had included all neccessary icons for the app. I did have them all.

This is my info.plist:

[image]

Under "Icon file", "Icon files", and "Icon files (iOS 5)", I did provide a default 57x57 icon, an icon for iPad, and an icon for iPhone. They are present in the same directory of the project file.

What am I missing here? (I tried to add entries called "CFBundleIcons/File/Files", but there were no such entries to be added).

---

Below is my updated info.plist after I followed rmaddy's advise:

[image]

Now that all the icon files have been updated properly with the correct dimensions (no warning yellow triangle over the images on the Summary tab). Why am I still getting this same error message? What else do I miss?

Comment: Not sure as to how to fix the problem, but you do have a couple images that are in the wrong place. "Default.png" and the two screenshots (whatever those are) shouldn't be grouped in the "icon files" section, same with the ios 5 icon files. Also, the "could not verify dimensions" thing could be because you have no retina icon (114 x 114) and no icon for iPad (72 x 72). Not positive, but certainly some things to try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to ensure all of your icons and launch images are setup correctly is to go to the Summary tab for your project's target (or targets if more than one) in Xcode. On the Summary tab is a section for iPhone / iPod touch Deployment Info and another for iPad Deployment Info. In each of these two sections is a place for App Icons and Launch Images. Click on each and load the proper image. If a yellow warning triangle appears then the image is the wrong size or possible some other issue. Filling in all of the images this way will properly update your Info.plist with the correct entries.

The screen you posted makes it clear you are trying to put the launch image (Default.png) and some screen shots where your icons belong. Default.png is a launch image. The screen shots don't go anywhere in your project. They get loaded at iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. I followed your suggestion, and added all the app icons and launch images for both iPhone/iPod and iPad. The images were in the correct dimension, and no yellow triangle showing up on the images. However, I still got the exact same error message when I tried to validate my app. I'll post an update picture of my new info.plist

Comment: Just to cover the obvious - after adding everything properly, did you do another archive build and perform the validation on the new archive?

Comment: Yes, I did. After adding all the images, I cleaned the project, then re-built the project (it worked fine, and the new icon showed up on my iPad), and then archive built, and finally did the validation.

Comment: Perhaps the validator doesn't like your naming convention. Follow the guidelines shown in [Technical QA1686](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html). Note that the document hasn't been updated for retina iPads.

Comment: I will try that when I get home tonight. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Got it! After renaming the image files as the link suggested, it still didn't work. So, I decided to make a new project, then added the source codes to the new project, then built and validated the new project. And it worked! App submitted successfully. Thank you for your help!

Comment: "Filling in all of the images this way will properly update your Info.plist with the correct entries." - This isn't the case in my experience. Xcode 4.6.3 has some bugs with icon files, editing the Info.plist is sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I resolved the issue by making sure the names in the plist file matched the names of the files under General->App Icons. It has to have the exact same case