# How to specify icons for a universal iPhone/iPad app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How to specify icons for a universal iPhone/iPad app with all 4 versions (icon.png, icon@2x.png ... etc)?

Comment: See my answer and comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020872/how-do-you-define-cfbundleicons-cfbundleiconfiles-cfbundleiconfile/13021996#13021996

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I have live universal app on app store. **Refer attached image** for the image names.

**Icon-Small** is used in Settings app,
**Icon** is shown in iPhone Home screen and
**Icon-72** is shown in iPad Home screen.

**Refer second image for the image sizes**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you have to declare App Launcher icon images

```
Device      size                   retina display size
iphone     57*57  (icon.png)         114*114 (icon@2x)
iPad        72*72                    144*144

Launch Image size
Device      size        retina display size
iphone     320*480           640*960
iphone 5    640*1136 
iPad        768*1024         1536*2048
```

And to specifies your icons go to the Target then summary then you browse icon (manually) for all the device name doesn't matter but name not be same.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the default icon names..

> ```
> Iphone(non retina) :icon.png
> ```
>
> Iphone(retina) :icon@2x.png
>
> Ipad(Non retina) :Icon-72.png
>
> IPad(Retina) :Icon-72@2x.png

Answer (score 0):

Add a CFBundleIconFiles key of type Array to your Info.plist. The array should contain 2 string items: the filenames of the two icons. The OS will then automatically choose the correct icon for each platform based on their pixel dimensions.

Follow this link   [FOR UNIVERSAL APP ICON](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html)

Answer (score 0):

[image: image assets appicon]

I think you can create app icon set in images.xcassets and that will save a lot of time